# Create a theme function for form fields

Tags: theming

I need to theme certain form fields on the user profile form page differently from other fields, for which I am trying to create a theme function that outputs html its own way, not using theme_form_element(). The reason for defining a new theme function alternative to theme_form_element() is because the html output is dramatically different.

This is my code:

```
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'profile_form_element' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'element' => NULL,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

function mymodule_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['field_user_first_name']['#theme'] = 'profile_form_element';
    dpm($form['field_user_first_name']);
}

function theme_profile_form_element(&$variables) {
  $element = &$variables['element'];
  // my html processing would start here...
}
```

...but the theme function has NULL for $variables['element']. What am I doing wrong? I am attaching the structure of my form field (*field_user_first_name*), which was created through the UI at configuration > people > account settings > manage fields.

[image: form field dpm'd]

[image: form field dpm'd part2]

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your problem is with this:

```
$element = &$variables['element'];
```

I don't think you can assign a reference to an array element (the &), so try changing it to:

```
$element = $variables['element'];
```

and I don't see a 'element' element, so unless I'm blind you're trying to access an element that isn't there, so it will always return NULL;

Comment: So what do I need to pass in my hook_theme()? I thought 'element' would just collect the form field itself...

Comment: Im far from an expert on the Form API, but it looks to me like you are assigning $form['field_user_first_name']['#theme'] to the return value of the function, but in your dpm $form['field_user_first_name']['#theme'] doesn't have any sub-elements, so when you try to assign your variable, you're assigning something that isn't there. To know what $variables contains in your callback, dpm it

Comment: $variables comes blank, it has 3 keys 'element, 'context', 'theme_hook_original'->profile_form_element. Nothing for 'element', still don't know what am I doing wrong...